# PHP inarray function issue

Tags: php

I have this php code

```
$files_array = array();
$files_array = glob('*.aria2');
$files_array = str_replace('.aria2', '', $files_array);
array_push($files_array,"processing");
```

If i print result of $files_array

```
Array
(
    [0] => [LiveFish] Vanguard [AAC]
    [1] => [Riycou] K-Project [MP4 AAC 720p]
    [2] => processing
)
```

I use in_array code

```
if(!in_array($ff, $files_array))
{
listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);

}
```

Php return me an error

```
PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
```

My $files_array variable seems okay, if I use print_r, it was able to display the array value, why would php give me an error mention parameter 2 was null

Below is my full code structure

```
$files_array = array();
$files_array = glob('*.aria2');
$files_array = str_replace('.aria2', '', $files_array);
array_push($files_array,"processing");
print_r($files_array);


function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $i = 0;
    $list = array();

    foreach ( $ffs as $ff ){
        if ( $ff != '.' && $ff != '..' ){
            if ( strlen($ff)>=5 ) {
                $extension = array('.mkv', '.avi', '.mp4');
                $file_extension = substr($ff, -4);
                if ( in_array($file_extension,$extension )) {
                    $list[] = $ff;
                    echo dirname($ff) . $ff . "<br/>";
                    $fileName = $dir.'/'.$ff;
                }
            }
            if( is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff) )
                if(!in_array($ff, $files_array)) {
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                }
           }
        }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: If you move `$files_array = array();` just above the if block, does it work?

Comment: You are unsetting your array after the first loop, but continuing to loop, so the second time around the array is unset and you don't get anything useful. I think that's correct anyway, your indenting is throwing me off.

Comment: I took away unset, and rearrange my code, please check the edited version . Issue still persist.

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($files_array);
```

Don't do that **inside** the loop, or terminate the loop right after doing this with `break` or `return`. But don't continue looping back into the `in_array` call, of course that will break.

Since your edit you moved setting the array to outside the function, as such it is no longer in scope. Either import it using `global` keyword, or pass it as a parameter.

[Read more about variable scope and `global` on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Thanks. I removed unset . but issue still persist, code updated.

Comment: Please hesitate from changing the question code all the time, it's messy enough without proper indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in the beginning of your function:

```
global $files_array;
```

Documentation: https://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - second example.

Or pass as a parameter to function:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir, $files_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `$files_array` inside a function, it must be in global scope. Use [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword before the variable:

```
global $files_array;
```

At the start of the function.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
  global $files_array;
  $ffs = scandir($dir);
  $i = 0;
  $list = array();

  foreach ( $ffs as $ff ){
    if ( $ff != '.' && $ff != '..' ){
      if ( strlen($ff)>=5 ) {

        $extension = array('.mkv', '.avi', '.mp4');
        $file_extension = substr($ff, -4);
        if ( in_array($file_extension,$extension ))
        {
          $list[] = $ff;
          echo dirname($ff) . $ff . "<br/>";
          $fileName = $dir.'/'.$ff;

        }
      }
      if( is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff) )
        if(!in_array($ff, $files_array))
        {
          listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        }
    }
  }
  return $list;
}
```